# Change React Native App Name Based On Mobile Language Direction

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native

Is it possible to change app name before installation of APK based on target mobile language direction ?

For example if the app name is Hello in ltr language phone , now if phone language is Persian (which is rtl ) we have "سلام" (equivalent of hello) for the app name

Comment: Do you use dictionary in your app?

Comment: no i have not use dictionary

Comment: How do you want to convert hello to سلام?

Comment: aha,now i got what you mean , suppose that i have a Json file that these translations are written in it . or even for just example testing suppose that i want to have a ternary for name depending on phone language direction